# After Talos installation jupyter notebook breaks (kernel going on and off)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, talos

What is the best way to install talos because whenever i am installing talos i am getting error as

```
[I 10:35:48.748 NotebookApp] Adapting to protocol v5.1 for kernel 7e583387-30ab-46fa-92b3-9aa67ee40139
[E 10:35:48.752 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in /api/kernels/7e583387-30ab-46fa-92b3-9aa67ee40139/channels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\websocket.py", line 498, in _run_callback
        result = callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\handlers.py", line 258, in open
        super(ZMQChannelsHandler, self).open()
      File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\notebook\base\zmqhandlers.py", line 168, in open
        self.send_ping, self.ping_interval, io_loop=loop,
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'io_loop'
```

I have been using google colab for sometime but i recently switched back to jupyter notebook for my project.

I remember i installed "Anaconda3-5.2.0-Windows-x86_64" on my windows 10 Laptop

List of packages:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py36he6757f0_0
alabaster                 0.7.10           py36hcd07829_0
anaconda                  5.2.0                    py36_3
anaconda-client           1.6.14                   py36_0
anaconda-navigator        1.8.7                    py36_0
anaconda-project          0.8.2            py36hfad2e28_0
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py36_0
astroid                   1.6.3                    py36_0
astropy                   3.0.2            py36h452e1ab_1
attrs                     18.1.0                   py36_0
babel                     2.5.3                    py36_0
backcall                  0.1.0                    py36_0
backports                 1.0              py36h81696a8_1
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0            py36h79ab834_2
beautifulsoup4            4.6.0            py36hd4cc5e8_1
bitarray                  0.8.1            py36hfa6e2cd_1
bkcharts                  0.2              py36h7e685f7_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blaze                     0.11.3           py36h8a29ca5_0
bleach                    2.1.3                    py36_0
blosc                     1.14.3               he51fdeb_0
bokeh                     0.12.16                  py36_0
boto                      2.48.0           py36h1a776d2_1
bottleneck                1.2.1            py36hd119dfa_0
bzip2                     1.0.6                hfa6e2cd_5
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0
certifi                   2018.4.16                py36_0
cffi                      1.11.5           py36h945400d_0
chardet                   3.0.4            py36h420ce6e_1
click                     6.7              py36hec8c647_0
cloudpickle               0.5.3                    py36_0
clyent                    1.2.2            py36hb10d595_1
colorama                  0.3.9            py36h029ae33_0
comtypes                  1.1.4                    py36_0
conda                     4.5.4                    py36_0
conda-build               3.10.5                   py36_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1
conda-verify              2.0.0            py36h065de53_0
console_shortcut          0.1.1                h6bb2dd7_3
contextlib2               0.5.5            py36he5d52c0_0
cryptography              2.2.2            py36hfa6e2cd_0
curl                      7.60.0               h7602738_0
cycler                    0.10.0           py36h009560c_0
cython                    0.28.2           py36hfa6e2cd_0
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py36hfa6e2cd_0
dask                      0.17.5                   py36_0
dask-core                 0.17.5                   py36_0
datashape                 0.5.4            py36h5770b85_0
decorator                 4.3.0                    py36_0
distributed               1.21.8                   py36_0
docutils                  0.14             py36h6012d8f_0
entrypoints               0.2.3            py36hfd66bb0_2
et_xmlfile                1.0.1            py36h3d2d736_0
fastcache                 1.0.2            py36hfa6e2cd_2
filelock                  3.0.4                    py36_0
flask                     1.0.2                    py36_1
flask-cors                3.0.4                    py36_0
freetype                  2.8                  h51f8f2c_1
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0
gevent                    1.3.0            py36hfa6e2cd_0
glob2                     0.6              py36hdf76b57_0
greenlet                  0.4.13           py36hfa6e2cd_0
h5py                      2.7.1            py36h3bdd7fb_2
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py36_2
html5lib                  1.0.1            py36h047fa9f_0
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1
idna                      2.6              py36h148d497_1
imageio                   2.3.0                    py36_0
imagesize                 1.0.0                    py36_0
intel-openmp              2018.0.0                      8
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py36_0
ipython                   6.4.0                    py36_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0            py36h3c5d0ee_0
ipywidgets                7.2.1                    py36_0
isort                     4.3.4                    py36_0
itsdangerous              0.24             py36hb6c5a24_1
jdcal                     1.4                      py36_0
jedi                      0.12.0                   py36_1
jinja2                    2.10             py36h292fed1_0
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2
jsonschema                2.6.0            py36h7636477_0
jupyter                   1.0.0                    py36_4
jupyter_client            5.2.3                    py36_0
jupyter_console           5.2.0            py36h6d89b47_1
jupyter_core              4.4.0            py36h56e9d50_0
jupyterlab                0.32.1                   py36_0
jupyterlab_launcher       0.10.5                   py36_0
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py36h12c3424_0
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py36hd1c21d2_0
libcurl                   7.60.0               hc4dcbb0_0
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
libpng                    1.6.34               h79bbb47_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
libssh2                   1.8.0                hd619d38_4
libtiff                   4.0.9                hb8ad9f9_1
libxml2                   2.9.8                hadb2253_1
libxslt                   1.1.32               hf6f1972_0
llvmlite                  0.23.1           py36hcacf6c6_0
locket                    0.2.0            py36hfed976d_1
lxml                      4.2.1            py36heafd4d3_0
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markupsafe                1.0              py36h0e26971_1
matplotlib                2.2.2            py36h153e9ff_1
mccabe                    0.6.1            py36hb41005a_1
menuinst                  1.4.14           py36hfa6e2cd_0
mistune                   0.8.3            py36hfa6e2cd_1
mkl                       2018.0.2                      1
mkl-service               1.1.2            py36h57e144c_4
mkl_fft                   1.0.1            py36h452e1ab_0
mkl_random                1.0.1            py36h9258bd6_0
more-itertools            4.1.0                    py36_0
mpmath                    1.0.0            py36hacc8adf_2
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py36he980bc4_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
multipledispatch          0.5.0                    py36_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py36_0
nbconvert                 5.3.1            py36h8dc0fde_0
nbformat                  4.4.0            py36h3a5bc1b_0
networkx                  2.1                      py36_0
nltk                      3.3.0                    py36_0
nose                      1.3.7            py36h1c3779e_2
notebook                  5.5.0                    py36_0
numba                     0.38.0           py36h830ac7b_0
numexpr                   2.6.5            py36hcd2f87e_0
numpy                     1.14.3           py36h9fa60d3_1
numpy-base                1.14.3           py36h555522e_1
numpydoc                  0.8.0                    py36_0
odo                       0.5.1            py36h7560279_0
olefile                   0.45.1                   py36_0
openpyxl                  2.5.3                    py36_0
openssl                   1.0.2o               h8ea7d77_0
packaging                 17.1                     py36_0
pandas                    0.23.0           py36h830ac7b_0
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hb2460c7_1
pandocfilters             1.4.2            py36h3ef6317_1
parso                     0.2.0                    py36_0
partd                     0.3.8            py36hc8e763b_0
path.py                   11.0.1                   py36_0
pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py36_0
patsy                     0.5.0                    py36_0
pep8                      1.7.1                    py36_0
pickleshare               0.7.4            py36h9de030f_0
pillow                    5.1.0            py36h0738816_0
pip                       10.0.1                   py36_0
pkginfo                   1.4.2                    py36_1
pluggy                    0.6.0            py36hc7daf1e_0
ply                       3.11                     py36_0
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15           py36h60b8f86_0
psutil                    5.4.5            py36hfa6e2cd_0
py                        1.5.3                    py36_0
pycodestyle               2.4.0                    py36_0
pycosat                   0.6.3            py36h413d8a4_0
pycparser                 2.18             py36hd053e01_1
pycrypto                  2.6.1            py36hfa6e2cd_8
pycurl                    7.43.0.1         py36h74b6da3_0
pyflakes                  1.6.0            py36h0b975d6_0
pygments                  2.2.0            py36hb010967_0
pylint                    1.8.4                    py36_0
pyodbc                    4.0.23           py36h6538335_0
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py36_0
pyparsing                 2.2.0            py36h785a196_1
pyqt                      5.9.2            py36h1aa27d4_0
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py36_0
pytables                  3.4.3            py36he6f6034_1
pytest                    3.5.1                    py36_0
pytest-arraydiff          0.2                      py36_0
pytest-astropy            0.3.0                    py36_0
pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                    py36_0
pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                    py36_0
pytest-remotedata         0.2.1                    py36_0
python                    3.6.5                h0c2934d_0
python-dateutil           2.7.3                    py36_0
pytz                      2018.4                   py36_0
pywavelets                0.5.2            py36hc649158_0
pywin32                   223              py36hfa6e2cd_1
pywinpty                  0.5.1                    py36_0
pyyaml                    3.12             py36h1d1928f_1
pyzmq                     17.0.0           py36hfa6e2cd_1
qt                        5.9.5            vc14he4a7d60_0  [vc14]
qtawesome                 0.4.4            py36h5aa48f6_0
qtconsole                 4.3.1            py36h99a29a9_0
qtpy                      1.4.1                    py36_0
requests                  2.18.4           py36h4371aae_1
rope                      0.10.7           py36had63a69_0
ruamel_yaml               0.15.35          py36hfa6e2cd_1
scikit-image              0.13.1           py36hfa6e2cd_1
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py36h53aea1b_0
scipy                     1.1.0            py36h672f292_0
seaborn                   0.8.1            py36h9b69545_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
setuptools                39.1.0                   py36_0
simplegeneric             0.8.1                    py36_2
singledispatch            3.4.0.3          py36h17d0c80_0
sip                       4.19.8           py36h6538335_0
six                       1.11.0           py36h4db2310_1
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3
snowballstemmer           1.2.1            py36h763602f_0
sortedcollections         0.6.1                    py36_0
sortedcontainers          1.5.10                   py36_0
sphinx                    1.7.4                    py36_0
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py36hbbac3d2_1
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.0.1            py36hb5e5916_1
spyder                    3.2.8                    py36_0
sqlalchemy                1.2.7            py36ha85dd04_0
sqlite                    3.23.1               h35aae40_0
statsmodels               0.9.0            py36h452e1ab_0
sympy                     1.1.1            py36h96708e0_0
tblib                     1.3.2            py36h30f5020_0
terminado                 0.8.1                    py36_1
testpath                  0.3.1            py36h2698cfe_0
tk                        8.6.7                hcb92d03_3
toolz                     0.9.0                    py36_0
tornado                   5.0.2                    py36_0
traitlets                 4.3.2            py36h096827d_0
typing                    3.6.4                    py36_0
unicodecsv                0.14.1           py36h6450c06_0
urllib3                   1.22             py36h276f60a_0
vc                        14                   h0510ff6_3
vs2015_runtime            14.0.25123                    3
wcwidth                   0.1.7            py36h3d5aa90_0
webencodings              0.5.1            py36h67c50ae_1
werkzeug                  0.14.1                   py36_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py36_0
widgetsnbextension        3.2.1                    py36_0
win_inet_pton             1.0.1            py36he67d7fd_1
win_unicode_console       0.5              py36hcdbd4b5_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
wrapt                     1.10.11          py36he5f5981_0
xlrd                      1.1.0            py36h1cb58dc_1
xlsxwriter                1.0.4                    py36_0
xlwings                   0.11.8                   py36_0
xlwt                      1.3.0            py36h1a4751e_0
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2
zeromq                    4.2.5                hc6251cf_0
zict                      0.1.3            py36h2d8e73e_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h8395fce_2
```

I am very sure there is some version problem.

If you can suggest me what version of ananconda to install i will remove my all old packages using 'Uninstall-Anaconda3.exe' under C:\Users\XXXX\Anaconda3

Oh i forgot i have tried installing talos by

1. pip install talos
2. pip install git+https://github.com/autonomio/talos.git@daily-dev

Comment: For now i have uninstalled older version of anaconda and installed newer version and things seems to be ok. I mean "import talos" is working. later today i will play more with talos and would get better picture

Comment: Hi, I am having the exact same issue. My kernel keeps breaking after installing talos. Did you solve it? And how?